# Regular Exp. Match

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression to match

> 112/AA-BB

but not

> 111/XX-ZZ-2

What I've tried so far is : `\b[0-9]{3}(?:\W[A-Z]{2}){2}\b`. However, this also matches the second input. Is there a way to limit the whole expression to 9 characters or a work around?

Here's [a link to my tests](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%28%3F%3A%5CW%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%7D%29%7B2%7D%5Cb&i=112%2FAA-BB%2C%20%20111%2FXX-ZZ-2%0D%0A&r=&o=n).

Comment: is the reason you don't want the second one to match is the length?  Or do you only want to match up to the second hyphen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like \b is still counting `-` as a word boundary i.e. an end of word. So what you could do is add a negative look ahead that prevents your string from matching if it's followed by a dash :

```
\b\d{3}\/[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}\b(?!-)
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/4AJksX/1).

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear for me what exactly you want it to match, but possibly you can add lookahead of specified-length string ending with comma, space or other delimiter by using `(?=.{9}[,\s$])`.

So, the result will be like [that](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3D.%7B9%7D%5B%2C%5Cs%24%5D%29%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%28%3F%3A%5CW%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%7D%29%7B2%7D&i=112%2FAA-BB%2C%20%20111%2FXX-ZZ-2%0D%0A112%2FAA-BB%0D%0A111%2FXX-ZZ-2&r=&o=n):

```
(?=.{9}[,\s$])[0-9]{3}(?:\W[A-Z]{2}){2}
```